# React context not shared between components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, use-context

I use a react context between 2 components, however when I set the value this context in the child filtersBar component, it does not update  or useffect in the second child map component.

contextprovider

```
const SearchContext = createContext();

const SearchContextProvider = ({children}) => {
const [contextValue, setContextValue] = useState(null);            
    return (
    <SearchContext.Provider value={[contextValue, setContextValue]}>
        {children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
);
```

index.js

```
 <SearchContextProvider>
    <FiltersBar/>
      <Map/>
    </SearchContextProvider>
```

Filtersbar.js

```
const FiltersBar = () => {
        const [searchContext,setSearchContext] = useContext(SearchContext);
        const [searchLocationResult, setsearchLocationResult] = useState(null);
        const [inputSearchLocation, setinputSearchLocation] = useState("");
  
 useEffect(() => {
// stuff
                 searchContext.autocompleteLocation = [46.6, 8.5]
              setSearchContext(searchContext)

        }, [searchLocationResult, inputSearchLocation]);
```

Map.js

```
const Map = () => {
  
    const [searchContext, setSearchContext] = useContext(SearchContext);


    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("use effect map"+JSON.stringify(searchContext))
    }, [searchContext]);
```

I never see this use effect map console log message. What am I missing?

Comment: `setSearchContext(searchContext)` This won't cause SearchContextProvider to render, because the state has not changed. Is it like this in the real code too, or is that just because you (over)simplified it to ask the question?

Comment: you are right I have cut too much code. the searchContext is not null when setting it. I edited the code

Comment: Your edited code *still* won't cause a rerender. You need to create a new state, not mutate the old one. Maybe this doesn't matter and your real code is doing it fine, but i can only work with what i've got.

Comment: this new state should be created into the filterbar? or searchContextProvider? can you guide me through? I am new to this

Comment: The location is fine, you just need to copy the state, not mutate the original state. I've added an answer to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you've shown is an accurate representation of your real code, the problem is that you're mutating state, not creating a new one. When you set state, react does a `===` between the state before and the state after. It sees that they're the same object, so it thinks nothing has changed, and it does nothing.

So instead of this:

```
searchContext.autocompleteLocation = [46.6, 8.5]
setSearchContext(searchContext)
```

Do this:

```
const newState = {
  ...searchContext,
  autocompleteLocation: [46.6, 8.5]
}
setSearchContext(newState);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this

```
useEffect(() => {
  /// stuff
  setSearchContext(searchContext) // ----> here
}, [searchLocationResult, inputSearchLocation]);
```

`searchContext` never changes. it always null, you awlays set `null` to `setSearchContext` function.
Maybe you only get first console.log like `use effect mapnull` when reload or component init

Comment: sorry I have edited my oversimplified sample, it is never null

Comment: Haha. the last answer from you in first thread point that. setSearchContext(searchContext) This won't cause SearchContextProvider to render

Comment: I need to update the context infact to be spread to my 2 components, how would you do it. I have tried set the searchcontext with an intermediate variable but still not refreshing the map component

Answer (score 0):

React hook is a bit different with React state in Class component. React hook consider state changes only if it's new object, u should create new object when you update the state.

You can update the useEffect of FiltersBar as below:
`Filtersbar.js`

```js
const FiltersBar = () => {
        ...
 useEffect(() => {
// stuff
    setSearchContext({...searchContext, autocompleteLocation: [46.6, 8.5]})

}, [searchLocationResult, inputSearchLocation]);
```